# jQuery ColorBox grouping of all images in all posts (or all posts on a page, like blog page) (Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, colorbox, posts

Does anyone know how can we group all images in all posts in Wordpress blog using jQuery ColorBox plugin? I am trying to achieve ColorBox effects that group all images in the whole blog into a gallery where you can go back and forth through all these images in ColorBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ColorBox can only group elements that exist within your document.  So if you have all the links, or whatever you use, on a single page - then yes, just group them together by setting colorbox's rel property.  If you are trying to group elements that are spread out over several documents then that is not possible.

Comment: Well, i'm not sure if you are familiar with Wordpress, but the page I'm building is a home / front page that have the_content of each post, and there is 10 posts on the front page (which is the blog). Now on each post, there will be an image (thumbnail) displayed, what I want to achieve is whenever an user click on the thumbnail belong to post 1, they will be able to go to next image, belong to post 2, within the same colorbox.

Comment: You should be able to do that then. I don't use Wordpress or have experience with any of the wordpress colorbox modules, but all you would need would be some selector that matches all of those thumbnails, then assign colorbox to it with the rel property specified.

Comment: Example: $('a.thumbnail').colorbox({rel:'my gallery'});  You would replace 'a.thumbnail' with a selector that matches all of your homepage image link elements.

Comment: Jack, thanks! ColorBox is awesome! Thank you so much for your work. Yes, I fixed it now, it's all working!